# Triangulation of Klein Bottle

Tags: general-topology, simplex, triangulation, klein-bottle

Is this triangulation of klein bottle right? I need to make a 10 vertices triangulation of klein bottle and i don't know almost anything about triangulation but tried to do one anyway and not sure if it's right. What i know is triangles must not connect more than one vertice or one edge. And an edge only be edge of one or two triangles. But AF edge is edge of four triangles if i get that right, so i don't know what am i supposed to do.

(there is an F on the right middle too i forgot to write it)
[image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bScfw.jpg)

Comment: I looked too many questions but didn't see that, thanks. And i think my triangulation is wrong but i dont know how to create one with exactly 10 vertices

Comment: It looks right, and there are 10 vertices.

Comment: But Euler characteristic doesn't work. There are 10 vertices, 20 faces 10+20=30 so i need 30 edges to make it work but there are only 27. 10 - 27 + 20 = 3 ≠ 0

Comment: Count the edges again. There are 30.

Comment: https://imgur.com/1P1ljtW red ones are duplicated edges and i think they shouldn't be counted.

Comment: The edges numbered 6, $FA$ and $AF$ are distinct. They traverse a circle from $NP$ to $SP$ in different senses.

Comment: I don't understand at all but using what you said there is an AF and an FA. But that make 28 because there is 2 AF and 2 FA. And there is 24 and 13 are duplicated too so that makes 30. 10-30+20=0. I think that would work. Thank you so much wise man!